# Multiple voices (divisi) in one part

Tags: lilypond

In LilyPond, how do you produce results like this? I want to go from a regular section to divisi, but I am unable to figure it out.

[image]

I attempted to use `\parallelMusic` and `\new StaffGroup`, but those basically created a new time signature and I had to set the key again. Additionally, the aesthetics were strange.

How can I do something that will produce the same results as something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to typeset that music using two different parts. Then, you specify `\RemoveEmptyStaves` to hide the lower voice for the first few measures. If it's the opening measures you're hiding, you also need to override some `\Score` presets. Input into their correct `\context`s, the necessary code will be:

```
\version "2.18.2"

sop = \relative c'' {
  c8 e g e c e g e |
  c e g e c e g e |
  c e g e c e g e |
  c e g e c e g e |
  c e g e c e g e |
  c e g e c e g e |
}

alt = \relative c'' {
  R1 |
  R |
  R |
  R |
  R |
  c2 e4 g |
}

\layout {
  \context { 
    \Staff \RemoveEmptyStaves 
  }
  \context {
    \Score
    \override VerticalAxisGroup.remove-first = ##t
  }
}

\score{
  \context StaffGroup <<
    \sop
    \alt
  >>
}
```

[image]

See more [here](http://lsr.di.unimi.it/LSR/Item?id=307) at the LilyPond Snippet Repository.

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much for providing an example, it made it a lot more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Googling "lilypond multiple voices" could've helped ;) Depending on what you want to do exactly there's multiple options: http://lilypond.org/doc/v2.18/Documentation/notation/multiple-voices

For longer passages it would be: (example from the guide)

```
\new Staff <<
  \new Voice = "first"
    { \voiceOne r8 r16 g e8. f16 g8[ c,] f e16 d }
  \new Voice= "second"
    { \voiceTwo d16 c d8~ d16 b c8~ c16 b c8~ c16 b8. }
>>
```

I.e. you simply need to explicitly declare the separate voices